# Nodemon app crashed error message with --exec option

Tags: node.js, lint, nodemon

I'm facing an issue with my nodeJs application. I'm running the app with docker by doing docker compose up and a mongodb database.
I want to have nodemon running my application so each time a changes is made in the code it's also run a linter.

In my package.json file, here are my script:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon index.js --exec 'npm run lint && node'",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "lint": "eslint ./src/**/*.js",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:docker": "docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.test.yml run test"
  },
```

If I run it like that I'm gonna have the following error (no more info on the issue just this error message):

**> [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...**

I tried everything I fond on internet regarding this error (update the node modules, killing all node instance of my machine, ...) . But nothing fix this.

Previsouly it was working fine on my machine, but I updated my mongo version to 4.2 and now it's not working anymore.

But if I change my dev script **from**  `"dev": "nodemon index.js --exec 'npm run lint && node'",` **to**   `"dev": "nodemon index.js",`. It's working fine, so I assume that something wrong is happening because of the --exec option.

I also tried to replace the --exec option by a nodemon.json file like that :

```
{
  "events": {
    "restart": "npm run lint",
    "start": "npm run lint"
  }
}
```

But it's not  working the npm run lint is never triggered.

Do you have any idea why the --exec is causing an issue here ? Or any leads I could look up a bit?

Thank you !

EDIT -------------------

Main DockerFile :

```
FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

setup/DockerFile

```
FROM mongo:4.2

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/configs

# Install app dependencies
COPY replicaSet.js .
COPY setup.sh .

ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/bash" ]
CMD ["./setup.sh"]
```

setup/replicaSet.js

```
rsconf = {
  _id: 'rs0',
  members: [
    { _id: 0, host: 'mongo-rs0-1:27017' },
    { _id: 1, host: 'mongo-rs0-2:27017' },
    { _id: 2, host: 'mongo-rs0-3:27017' },
  ],
}

rs.initiate(rsconf)

rs.conf()
```

setup/ setup.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

echo ******************************************************
echo Starting the replica set
echo ******************************************************

sleep 20 | echo Sleeping
mongo mongodb://mongo-rs0-1:27017 replicaSet.js
```

mongo-rs0-1/Dockerfile

```
FROM mongo:4.2

# Workdir configs directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/configs

# Copy config files
COPY mongo.conf .

EXPOSE 27017

CMD ["--config", "./mongo.conf"]
```

./mongo.conf file

```
replication:
   oplogSizeMB: 1024
   replSetName: rs0
```

docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'

services:
  ***_api:
    image: ***_api:latest
    container_name: ***_api
    build: .
    command: npm run dev
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - '${PORT}:${PORT}'
    depends_on:
      - 'redis'
      - 'setup-rs'
    env_file: .env
    tty: true

  mongo-rs0-1:
    image: 'mongo-start'
    build: ./mongo-rs0-1
    logging:
      driver: none
    ports:
      - '${MONGO_PORT}:27017'
    volumes:
      - ./.dbdata/mongo-rs0-1/data:/data/db
    depends_on:
      - 'mongo-rs0-2'
      - 'mongo-rs0-3'

  mongo-rs0-2:
    image: 'mongo:4.2'
    command: --replSet ${MONGO_REPLICA_SET_NAME} --oplogSize 128
    logging:
      driver: none
    ports:
      - '${MONGO_PORT_2}:27017'
    volumes:
      - ./.dbdata/mongo-rs0-2/data:/data/db

  mongo-rs0-3:
    image: 'mongo:4.2'
    command: --replSet ${MONGO_REPLICA_SET_NAME} --oplogSize 128
    logging:
      driver: none
    ports:
      - '${MONGO_PORT_3}:27017'
    volumes:
      - ./.dbdata/mongo-rs0-3/data:/data/db

  setup-rs:
    image: 'setup-rs'
    build: ./setup
    depends_on:
      - 'mongo-rs0-1'

  redis:
    container_name: redis_***
    image: 'redis:alpine'
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '${REDIS_PORT}:${REDIS_PORT}'

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: ***-network
```

Comment: For info, I also tried with very basics script (console.log('test')) on the dev script and it's the same issue so it's not coming from lint && node script.

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile?

Comment: Sure ! I added the dockerfile in the EDIT part of the post ! thank you :)

Comment: In your main Dockerfile, it says ```CMD ["npm", "start"]``` but the script that has the linter is actually ```npm run dev```

Comment: The dev script is ran by the services command :  command: npm run dev in the docker-compose.yml file